# UTF8 Icon CSS Bundling/Minification

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

Hoping someone can assist me here and stop me banging my head against a wall.
I've got a CSS file with a load of UTF-8 Icon Sequences

e.g.

```css
.icon-thing2:before {
  content: "\e01e";
}
.icon-test:before {
  content: "\e01f";
}
```

When bundling/minification (using the System.Web.Optimization namespace) is disabled everything works fine, however when turned on the unicode characters get rendered in the CSS bundle as "?".

I've tried adding the code below to the top of the CSS file and moved it into it's own bundle to no avail.
    @charset "UTF-8";

I can't see any other encoding declarations needed, the layout is already defined as UTF-8.

Any idea how I can stop it from doing that?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: After some further investigation, it does seem to be the "CssMinify" part of the System.Web.Optimization" framework that's causing the issue.

It's strange as this has worked fine in a similar project.

Wonder if the newer version is doing something it shouldn't be.

Comment: found the issue, I was specifying an encoding in the globalization settings in the Web.Config, correctly using UTF-8 for this corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, I was specifying an encoding in the globalization settings in the Web.Config, correctly using UTF-8 for this corrected the issue.